# Carousel with tabs: adjust active tab when carousel slides to next or previous slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I have a Twitter Bootstrap 3 carousel without *indicator buttons*.
Instead of those indicator buttons, I use tabs (which I style accordingly in my CSS).
This way, the user has an idea what each slide is (based on the tab label), so it's easier for him to go to the slide he's interested in.

[image: whatIsCarousel]

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="whatIsCarousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="slide0.png">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="slide1.png">
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#whatIsCarousel">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#whatIsCarousel">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>
<ul class="nav nav-justified" id="whatIsCarouselButtons">
    <li class="active" data-target="#whatIsCarousel" data-slide-to="0">
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#">Slide 0</a>
    </li>
    <li data-target="#whatIsCarousel" data-slide-to="1">
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#">Slide 1</a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

The CSS is irrelevant, but [source code is here](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner-website/blob/master/website/optaplannerWebsite.css).

The tabs works well: When I click on one of the tabs, the carousel slides to the appropriate slide, and the correct tab becomes active (highlights).

The carousel controls (left and right) work partially: when I click on one of the controls (or it slides automatically), the carousel slides to the appropriate slide, but the active tab does not change. **How do I make the active tab change when the carousel slides?**

Here's what I got so far in my javascript:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $carousel.carousel();
    $('#whatIsCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function(e) {
        var from = active.index();
        var next = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var to = next.index();

        // Is to the index of the next slide?
        // How do I find tab that needs to be active next?
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this way could help you :

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/116312

**Js** :

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel();
    $('#whatIsCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function(e) {
        var from = $('.nav li.active').index();
        var next = $(e.relatedTarget);
        var to =  next.index();

        // This could interest you
        $('.nav li').removeClass('active').eq(to).addClass('active');

    });
});
```

**Focus on** :

```
$('.nav li').removeClass('active').eq(to).addClass('active');
```

*You remove `active` class from all tabs, and add it to the tabs that has the same index.*

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Because I already have .nav elements I needed to change is like this:

    $('#whatIsCarouselButtons').find('li').removeClass('active').eq(to).addClass('active');

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval:   4000
    });

    var clickEvent = false;
    $('#myCarousel').on('click', '.nav a', function() {
            clickEvent = true;
            $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');        
    }).on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e) {
        if(!clickEvent) {
            var count = $('.nav li').length -1;
            var current = $('.nav li.active');
            current.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
            var id = parseInt(current.data('slide-to')) +1;
            if(count+1 == id) {
                $('.nav li').first().addClass('active');    
            }
        }
        clickEvent = false;
    });
});
```